# A Well-Defined Bijection on An Equivalence Class

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, equivalence-relations

---

### DATA:

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a surjective function. Define a relation $\sim$ on $X$ by
$$a\sim b~\iff~f(a)=f(b).$$
Let $S=X/{\sim}$, namely let $S$ be the set of equivalence classes of elements of $X$ under the equivalence relation $\sim$. Define a function $q:X\rightarrow S$ by
$$\forall~a\in X~q(a)=[a].$$
Lastly, define $\overline{f}:S\rightarrow Y$ by
$$\forall~a\in X~\overline{f}([a])=f(a).$$

---

### QUEST:

> $\dagger_1\hspace{0.5cm}$Is $\overline{f}$ well-defined?
>
> $\dagger_2\hspace{0.5cm}$Is $\overline{f}$ a surjection? $\leftarrow$ Unsure about this one.
>
> $\dagger_3\hspace{0.5cm}$Is $\overline{f}$ an injection?

---

### KNOWN:

$\overline{f}\circ q = f$ $\leftarrow$ What is the utility of this for the quest?

---

### DIAGRAM:

$\hspace{4.6cm}$[image]

---

### THOUGHTS:

> $\dagger_1^{\star}\hspace{.5cm}$"$\overline{f}$ well-defined": $ [a]=[b]\implies \overline{f}([a])=\overline{f}([b])$
>
> $\dagger_2\hspace{.5cm}$"$\overline{f}$ surjection": Want to show that $\forall ~y\in Y~\exists~[x]\in S$ s.t. $\overline{f}([x])=y$ $\leftarrow$ ???
>
> $\dagger_3^{\star}\hspace{.5cm}$"$\overline{f}$ injection": Want to show that $\overline{f}([a])=\overline{f}([b])\implies [a]=[b]$

$\star$ denotes the ones I think I've got so far.

---

### ATTEMPT:

$\dagger_1^{\star}\hspace{.5cm}$ $[a]=[b]\implies a\sim b \iff f(a)=f(b) \implies \overline{f}([a])=\overline{f}([b])$

$\dagger_2\hspace{.5cm}$ ...PENDING... $\leftarrow$ Unsure about this one.

$\dagger_3^{\star}\hspace{.5cm}$ $f([a])=f([b])\implies f(a)=f(b) \iff a\sim b \implies [a]=[b]$

---

### NOTES:

I suspect $q$ is to be used for the surjection proof.

---

Comment: Might be a good idea to stare at the definitions of well-defined, surjective and injective and then try and make some examples

Comment: Writing $P(a)\ \forall a \in X$ is so **wrong**. This is _not_ math, this is some absurd, nonsensical and abysmal abuse. If you have to, use "$\forall a \in X\ P(a)$". However, quantifiers like $\forall$ or $\exists$ are not just a shorthands, they have a _very precise_ meaning, and unless you _intend_ to use that precise meaning (or whatever the meaning of quantifier the context provides), it is usually best to write in _plain words_ "for all $a \in X$".

Comment: Right... OK... I'll change it!

Comment: @Trancot: Are you the same person as Barisa Barukh?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @Trancot Why don't you just edit the question with that account? You wouldn't have to send it for review, then...

Comment: Oops, i just rejected the edit because it looked like someone was trying to answer inside the edit.

Comment: I am limited to only a couple of questions in a 24-hour period. I am a curious person. Curiosity implies many questions. Many questions are a restriction on a single account.

Comment: That was me "answering".

Comment: @trancot You should edit using the same account that you asked the question with (unless you have enough rep on the second account to not have edits reviewed).

Comment: Where is my answer?

Comment: @Trancot: If you are the same user as the OP, and you suggest edits and those get accepted, this is a voting fraud. Please don't do that.

Comment: Oh, OK. Sorry. I didn't know. I won't do that. Actually, it was a mistake. I had thought I was Barisa when I made the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The answer is yes. Suppose $a\sim b$. Then $f(a) = f(b)$.  So the map $[a]\mapsto f(a)$ is well-defined.
2. Suppose $f(a) = f(b)$. Then $a\sim b$ so $[a] = [b]$; $\overline f$ is 1-1.
3. It is easy to see that the image of X under $f$ is equal to that of the image of $X/{\sim}$ under $\overline f$.  Therefore it is onto.

Comment: $a\sim b\implies [a]=[b]$

Comment: $f$ or $\overline{f}$?

Comment: In fact, $a\sim b\iff [a] = [b].$

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

It is well defined because if you can any two representatives of a class, they have the same image by $f$.

It is a sujection because for any $y\in Y$, you have an $x\in X$ so that $f(x)=y$ because $f$ is surjective and that $x$ is in its own class.

It is an injection because if you have two elements $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $X$ whose class have the same image by $\overline{f}$, then $x_1$ and $x_2$ have the same image by $f$ so they are in the same class. Which means that is two classes have the same image by $\overline{f}$, they are equal.

Comment: $f$ or $\overline{f}$?